# Shell glob results are quoted if no response

Tags: shell, substring, glob, quote

I want to use rsync like this:

```
EXCLUDES=('*~' '*.cfg')
rsync ${EXCLUDES[@]/#/--exclude=} SOURCE DEST
```

The expected result is:

```
rsync --exclude=*~ --exclude=*.cfg SOURCE DEST
```

but the result when glob has no result is:

```
rsync '--exclude=*~' '--exclude=*.cfg' SOURCE DEST
```

I'm charmed by the one-line solution `${EXCLUDES[@]/#/--exclude=}`. How can I prevent the glob expansion to quote the result? Or maybe another one-line solution?

Comment: Why do you think there are quotes? Is this `set -x` output? Can you give the expected and actual results in terms of program output, and not in terms of commands you feel that it should be equivalent to but believe they aren't (or  at least what makes you believe that)?

Comment: _"How to do to prevent the glob expansion to quote the result ?"_  This question is unclear.  Please elaborate.

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the behavior that you describe this way:

```
$ touch a~ b~ c.cfg
$ EXCLUDES=('*~' '*.cfg')
$ echo rsync ${EXCLUDES[@]/#/--exclude=} SOURCE DEST
rsync --exclude=*~ --exclude=*.cfg SOURCE DEST
```

If I understand the question that you are asking, you want the file names for the excludes expanded.  In that case, use:

```
$ EXCLUDES=(*~ *.cfg)
$ echo rsync "${EXCLUDES[@]/#/--exclude=}" SOURCE DEST
rsync --exclude=a~ --exclude=b~ --exclude=c.cfg SOURCE DEST
```

**Alternatively**, it might be that you are concerned about the globs in the output when there are no matching files, such as:

```
$ rm -f a~ b~ c.cfg
$ EXCLUDES=(*~ *.cfg)
$ echo rsync "${EXCLUDES[@]/#/--exclude=}" SOURCE DEST
rsync --exclude=*~ --exclude=*.cfg SOURCE DEST
```

To prevent those globs from appearing, use `nullglob` like this:

```
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ EXCLUDES=(*~ *.cfg)
$ echo rsync "${EXCLUDES[@]/#/--exclude=}" SOURCE DEST
rsync SOURCE DEST
```

`nullglob` causes unmatched globs to disappear.

**Notes**

1. When using `EXCLUDES=('*~' '*.cfg')`, no expansion occurs because the globs are in quotes.  If you want expansion, remove the quotes.
2. The array expansion, `${EXCLUDES[@]/#/--exclude=}` should be in double-quotes.  Without the double-quotes, *word-splitting* will be performed on the result and that will cause errors if any file name contains whitespace.